# Finding Dependency tag for rs2xml.jar

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Could you please help me to find Dependency tag for rs2xml.jar. i think it is really helpful for me. net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) as well as the [MvnRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) for the `rs2xml` JAR file and could not find it.  A Google search for a POM corresponding to this dependency also came up empty.  However, you can still manually install the JAR into your own local repository and then use it as if it were any other dependency.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\rs2xml.jar -DgroupId=net.proteanit.sql
    -DartifactId=rs2xml -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Replace the path `C:\rs2xml.jar` with the actual location on your computer where you downloaded the JAR.  To use the `rs2xml` dependency in your project, include the following tag in your POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.proteanit.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>rs2xml</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to extracrt the package: 
net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils
to import im my project.

[image]

It's works!

Before I tried to edit pom.xml with the sugestion :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.proteanit.sql</groupId>
<artifactId>rs2xml</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

But doesn't works... :(

https://github.com/wfrsilva/javaMySQL03_infoX